# Vue.js - Accessing the event in the handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am following [vue.js tutorial - method event handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers)

```
    <button v-on:click='handler'>handle this</button>
    .
    .
    .
    methods: {
                handler: function (event) {                
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
              }}
```

However when I try to display the event all i get is `{"isTrusted":true}`

When I tried `console.log(event.target.tagName)` I get an empty string.

I think I am supposed to get Button.

Comment: try <button type="button"  v-on:click='handler($event)'>handle this</button>

Comment: Have you tried logging `arguments` inside handler to see what's coming in?

Comment: check my answer, there's a codepen example as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/DakshMiglani/pen/pLRdyy?editors=1010) which I created.

My Vue Instance looks like:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        greet: (e) => {
            console.log(e.target.tagName);
        }
    },
})
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <button @click="greet">Yo, I'm a button</button>
</div>
```

and when i see the console, it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this

```
v-on:click="handler($event)"
```

Comment: There's too many reasons to -1 this, starting with *Try it like this*...